# sys.argv causes Index Error

Tags: python, api

This is my Poisson Process Script. The Problem it causes is the error i.e. at line 7 (`a = float(sys.argv[1])`)

> IndexError: List index out of range.

I am not been able to fix it. Please help me out in fixing it.

```
import random
import math
import sys
import time

# Expected number of arrivals per unit time.
a = float(sys.argv[1])
# Number of events
count = int(sys.argv[2])

# Function for testing API
def test_api():
    print "Testing API..."
    # TODO: Make request to the API

# Make a function iterable, by repeatedly calling it.
def make_iterable(func, *args):
    try:
        while 1:
            yield func(*args)
    except:
        pass

uni_rand = make_iterable(random.uniform, 0, 1)

# A generator for inter-arrival times.
inter_arrival = ( -(1./a)*math.log(u) for u in uni_rand)

# Generate inter-arrival times, then sleep for that long.
inter_arrival_iter = iter(inter_arrival)
for i in xrange(count):
    inter_arrival_seconds = inter_arrival_iter.next() * 3600.
    print "Sleeping for %f seconds." % inter_arrival_seconds
    time.sleep(inter_arrival_seconds)
    test_api()
```

Comment: Did you actually pass in command-line arguments when running the script?

Comment: seems like you are not providing command line arguments.

Comment: How would I pass the arguments from the host ?

Answer (score 2):

You don't "fix it", you pass arguments to the script.

```
./script.py 1.2 7
```

If you want to check if you have enough arguments beforehand then you need to check its length (`len(sys.argv)`).

Comment: Or use `try:  a = float(sys.argv[1]); except IndexError: sys.exit("Missing argument!"); except ValueError: sys.exit("First value should be a float!")`

Comment: How would I pass the arguments from the host ? –